# In a rainbow, why is the top colour red and violet on bottom even though red emerges farther (42 degrees) than violet (40) when seen in a single drop?

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction, dispersion

[image]

I don't understand this image or why primary rainbow has red at the top even though in a single drop red is deviated most.

Comment: Refraction for the blue (violet) light must be stronger than for the red. Where did you get these numbers (40-42 deg) from?

Comment: No, (40-42) are the angles at which the light emerges after second refraction wrt incoming white light. I realize the wording in the question isn't proper.

Comment: My answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/527295/157014) might also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You only see the color that aims at you. From the higher drops that is red. From the lower drops that is violet.

Comment: Thanks got it, that is also why rainbows are curved right?

Comment: Yes that’s right. You see a given color only from drops that are at a specific angle to you relative to the sun’s position.