# Rainbow formation

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, refraction

Please help me with my query regarding rainbow formation.
Many Books gave formation of only red and violet colour whereas middlemost colours are rising doubt.please check the following picture .My Questions are also marked there..

[image]

Comment: The middle colours have an index of refraction that is inbetween red and violet, and are considered to be obviously taken care of once you have taken care of the red and violet limits. There is only need to draw one droplet; geometry will automatically take care of the rest. You have only considered the single reflection case; there is also the double reflection case, which will be better drawn as another droplet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a rainbow show all of its colours?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/709484/)