# Why can't we see Rainbows from its end points?

Tags: optics, visible-light, refraction

We see Rainbows many times, but we always see them Horizontally or from Sideways. Why can't we see it from under it?/From the point where it starts or ends(end points)? I also want to stress on that, I am asking on **viewing part** and not about the formation, reason, causes of a rainbow.

Comment: Related question:
http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142149  .

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23647/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Why should this be reopened? The second question should answer everything, otherwise you have to clarify what you don't understand!

Comment: I have edited the question. If still not clear, please tell me. I will try to ask in someother way and re-edit it.